# how to find a string "<logging>enabled</logging>" in an XML file using python?

Tags: python

I need to find a string "enabled" in an XML file using python script.

I am able to fine a string "enabled" but when i try to find out for a string "enabled" it's not working.

Comment: string is "<logging>enabled</logging>"  not enabled

Comment: how about finding the tags named `logging` and checking if the value is `enabled` then?

Comment: Try to put your code for what you have achieved so far.

Comment: @Ajay  if the answer posted below helped, you may accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Using BeautifulSoup:

list_test.xml:

```
<logging>enabled</logging>
<logging>disabled</logging>
<logging>enabled</logging>
<logging>disabled</logging>
<logging>enabled</logging>
```

and then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('list_test.xml','r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "html.parser")
    for line in soup.find_all('logging'):
         if line.text == 'enabled':
             print(line.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
enabled
enabled
enabled
```

**EDIT:**

To get the complete tags:

Use:

```
print(line)
```

Instead of:

```
print(line.text)
```

Comment: I need to find out complete string like "<logging>enabled</logging>" not only enabled string.

Comment: @Ajay Edited my answer.